# Edit each individual extrude made by Curve to Mesh node

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm working on a tree root using geometry nodes. It currently looks like this:
[image: current result]

A circle gets extruded over a jagged curve with a set radius and tilt, which all works as expected. The circle itself has some noise on it to make the root less uniform. Here's how it looks without the size and tilt variation to better show how it looks:
[image: current result without size and tilt variation]

I would like for there to be less uniformity *along* the root as well. To do this I would need to introduce variation into every circle that gets extruded by the Curve to Mesh node. In short, my question is: If I create a mesh from a curve using Curve to Mesh, can I edit all the created extrudes individually? And, can I still use spline parameters such as the Factor when doing so?

The node setup looks as follows:
[image: geometry node setup]

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about it? What exactly do you want to do with it and how do you want to select the individual circles along the curve? By index? By factor? ...and which Blender verison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is that you first capture the index/factor of each individual point on the base curve using `Capture Attribute` (this must be done after resampling!).

These values are transferred to the individual cross-sections when using `Curve to Mesh`.

After converting to a mesh, you can use these values to select and change certain parts.

In this example, I simply move the segment/cross-section with the index number 2 a little on the Y-axis, but along the tangents of the original base curve:

[image]

PS: In the same way, you can of course capture any other value (e.g. the factor) in the base curve and then continue to use it, as each value captured in a point is transferred 1:1 to the segment/cross-section.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I forgot), this works! Thanks!